# Trying to update python2.7 program to fit python3.3 new syntax restrictions

Tags: python, iterator, generator

work through stream until goal is met
I am getting an error at the q=rs.next() line ... "AttributeError 'generator' object has no attribute 'next' ... is next no longer valid in python33?

```
while num_withCoordinates<stop_at:
    q=rs.next()
```

Comment: It looks like your code didn't make it into your question.

Comment: added the rest of the code for the whole while statment

Comment: Cool. It would also help to show the part where you define `rs`.

Comment: just pasted in the entire program sorry should have done that to begin with

Comment: it is parsing tweets and returning matches with geographic locations used to map geo locations

Comment: I figured it out rs.next() in python 2.7 is now rs.__next__() in python 3.3

Answer (score 2):

In Python3, `next` is changed to `__next__` for iterators.  But the best way of iterating (other than `for`) is to use the `next` function:

```
q = next(rs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `rs` is a generator, the correct syntax (both 2.7 and 3.x) is :

```
q = next(rs)
```